# Настройка нескольких ip в Ubuntu

Tags: сервер, unix, администрирование, ip, сеть

Я собрал из хлама, что бы был сервер (просто комп с ПО).

Ситуация полностью:
Я пишу на Java, написал SOAP сервис.
Смысл заключается в том, чтобы запрос от клиента приходил на один ip. Внутри приложение вызывает сервис, который должен обрабатываться на другом ip.

И как мне это сделать с одним пк?
Накатить две виртуалки и в них уже прописать?

Кстати, у меня статический ip от провайдера.

Comment: у вас есть 16 с лишним миллионов ipv4-адресов: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81

Comment: Это интересная, но бесполезная информация